# JQuery auto complete can't fetch values from database

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Hi i write code for a input text that uses jquery auto complete but jquery auto complete can't fetch data from mysql using my php code.
what is wrong in my code?
below is my javascript code

```
<link href="_style/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
});
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
</body>
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php
include "Connect.php";
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$qstring = "SELECT pName as value,pID FROM patient WHERE pName LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring, $connection);//query the database for entries containing the term
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))//loop through the retrieved values
{
$row['pName']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['pName']));
$row['pID']=(int)$row['pID'];
$row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
?>
```

help me to fix my code problems!

Comment: Is your php script returning data?

Comment: I check my php code without auto complete edit text and see my php code works properly!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is anything wrong in your jquery function but here what i see wrong in your php

Instead this :

```
   $row['pName']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['pName']));
```

Use this:

```
   $row['pName']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
```

When you use `AS` than you have to use that to fetch values

HERE IS THE COMPLETE CORRECTION TO YOUR PHP CODE

```
 $qstring = "SELECT pName as value,pID FROM patient WHERE pName LIKE '%".$term."%'";
 $result = mysql_query($qstring, $connection);

 $row_set = array(); //u have to define the row_set array 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     $row_set['pName']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
     $row_set['pID']=(int)$row['pID'];
 }

 echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: try changing the name of the array ... you are already using `row` for fetching

Comment: see my updated answer, i tested it and it is working , otherwise there is some problem in your jquery function

Comment: thanks for your help i can see data in firebug json but auto complete doesn't shows them!

Comment: autocomplete will not work in this case if you are `escaping` the value because that `persion` word will be converted to `unicode` you have to decode that `unicode`

Comment: How can i use auto complete with persian?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug to pull up the response. It will make a table of your JSON result for easy debugging.

Comment: How can i see JSON results in firebug?

Comment: Under the console tab in your F12 Menu. Expand the request made then Click on JSON.

Comment: OK thanks for your help i can see that php code works well and return data.But i can't see results with autocomplete!

Comment: I can see results in JSON but i can't see them in auto complete suggestion!